# Limit a stream and find out if there are pending elements

Tags: java, loops, iterator, java-8, java-stream

I have the following code that I want to translate to Java 8 streams:

```
public ReleaseResult releaseReources() {
    List<String> releasedNames = new ArrayList<>();

    Stream<SomeResource> stream = this.someResources();

    Iterator<SomeResource> it = stream.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext() && releasedNames.size() < MAX_TO_RELEASE) {
        SomeResource resource = it.next();
        if (!resource.isTaken()) {
            resource.release();
            releasedNames.add(resource.getName());
        }
    }

    return new ReleaseResult(releasedNames, it.hasNext(), MAX_TO_RELEASE);
}
```

Method `someResources()` returns a `Stream<SomeResource>` and `ReleaseResult` class is as follows:

```
public class ReleaseResult {

    private int releasedCount;

    private List<String> releasedNames;

    private boolean hasMoreItems;

    private int releaseLimit;

    public ReleaseResult(List<String> releasedNames, 
        boolean hasMoreItems, int releaseLimit) {

        this.releasedNames = releasedNames;
        this.releasedCount = releasedNames.size();
        this.hasMoreItems = hasMoreItems;
        this.releaseLimit = releaseLimit;
    }

    // getters & setters
}
```

My attempt so far:

```
public ReleaseResult releaseReources() {

    List<String> releasedNames = this.someResources()
        .filter(resource -> !resource.isTaken())
        .limit(MAX_TO_RELEASE)
        .peek(SomeResource::release)
        .map(SomeResource::getName)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new ReleasedResult(releasedNames, ???, MAX_TO_RELEASE);
}
```

The problem is that I can't find a way to know if there are pending resources to process. I've thought of using `releasedNames.size() == MAX_TO_RELEASE`, but this doesn't take into account the case where the stream of resources has *exactly* `MAX_TO_RELEASE` elements.

**Is there a way to do the same with Java 8 streams?**

**Note:** I'm not looking for answers like *"you don't have to do everything with streams"* or *"using loops and iterators is fine"*. I'm OK if using an iterator and a loop is the only way or just the best way. It's just that I'd like to know if there's a non-murky way to do the same.

Comment: Isn't `??? == releasedNames.size() < MAX_TO_RELEASE`?

Comment: @Tunaki, nope. It's possible that we have exactly `MAX_TO_RELEASE` elements in `releasedNames` and nothing is left in the stream.

Comment: With StreamEx it's possible to do `StreamEx.of(this.someResources()).mapLast(x -> {atomicFlag.set(true);return x;}).` (and all other your steps), but it's still really dirty, so I would not recommend this.

Comment: @TagirValeev I've been reviewing StreamEx and I really like it. I think it need more time to stabilize it's API, though. I mean packages names, maven artifacts etc

Comment: @TagirValeev Glad to hear that!

Comment: @TagirValeev Maybe `peekFirst()` and `peekLast()` methods in StreamEx? May I post an issue (enhancement)?

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: that `mapLast` doesn’t solve the issue of the OP who wants to know whether there’s an item *after* the last. But there’s a gap in the logic anyway. The source iterator’s `hasNext()` only tells whether there are more source elements but not whether they would pass the filter. But placing the `limit` after the `filter` implies that we’re dealing with the *number of matching elements*, which usually should apply to the `hasMoreItems` flag of the result as well. That’s how I interpreted it in my answer.

Comment: @Holger You're damn right regarding that flaw! The `hasMoreItems` flag only tells if there are pending elements in the stream, not if these pending elements match the predicate

Comment: @Holger, placing `mapLast` directly after the source ensures that it will be executed for last *source* element, not the last element passing the filter, limit, etc. The sequential implementation looks ahead one element to check whether current is the last in the source. So if the last source element is requested by the downstream steps, it will be executed, otherwise not. If last element passing the filter is desired, then just move `mapLast` after the filter.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner, [implemented](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/commit/1786c9c21043232cbd8cf94a7864f3e58ee6d482). Since 0.6.0 it will be possible to use `StreamEx.of(this.someResources()).peekLast(x -> lastConsumed.set(true))...`. You may also check [tests](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/commit/1786c9c21043232cbd8cf94a7864f3e58ee6d482#diff-6ccde6e30d77e1f01ca8c15c0638b3edR1583).

Comment: @TagirValeev That's what I call speed ;) Thank you very much for including these operations

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: why should the sequential implementation look ahead when the limit is exhausted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a nice way to do this. I've found a hack that does it lazily. What you can do is convert the `Stream` to an `Iterator`, convert the `Iterator` back to another `Stream`, do the `Stream` operations, then finally test the `Iterator` for a next element!

```
Iterator<SomeResource> it = this.someResource().iterator();
List<String> list = StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(it, Spliterator.ORDERED), false)
                                 .filter(resource -> !resource.isTaken())
                                 .limit(MAX_TO_RELEASE)
                                 .peek(SomeResource::release)
                                 .map(SomeResource::getName)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
return new ReleaseResult(list, it.hasNext(), MAX_TO_RELEASE);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you don’t wanna hear that you don’t need streams for everything and loops and iterators are fine, let’s demonstrate it by showing a clean solution, not relying on `peek`:

```
public ReleaseResult releaseReources() {
    return this.someResources()
        .filter(resource -> !resource.isTaken())
        .limit(MAX_TO_RELEASE+1)
        .collect(
            () -> new ReleaseResult(new ArrayList<>(), false, MAX_TO_RELEASE),
            (result, resource) -> {
                List<String> names = result.getReleasedNames();
                if(names.size() == MAX_TO_RELEASE) result.setHasMoreItems(true);
                else {
                    resource.release();
                    names.add(resource.getName());
                }
            },
            (r1, r2) -> {
                List<String> names = r1.getReleasedNames();
                names.addAll(r2.getReleasedNames());
                if(names.size() > MAX_TO_RELEASE) {
                    r1.setHasMoreItems(true);
                    names.remove(MAX_TO_RELEASE);
                }
            }
        );
}
```

This assumes that `// getters & setters` includes getters and setters for all non-`final` fields of your `ReleaseResult`. And that `getReleasedNames()` returns the list by reference. Otherwise you would have to rewrite it to provide a specialized `Collector` having special non-public access to `ReleaseResult` (implementing another builder type or temporary storage would be an unnecessary complication, it looks like `ReleaseResult` is already designed exactly for that use case).

We could conclude that for any nontrivial loop code that doesn’t fit into the stream’s intrinsic operations, you can find a collector solution that basically does the same as the loop in its `accumulator` function, but suffers from the requirement of always having to provide a `combiner` function. Ok, in this case we can prepend a `filter(…).limit(…)` so it’s not that bad…

I just noticed, if you ever dare to use that with a parallel stream, you need a way to reverse the effect of releasing the last element in the combiner in case the combined size exceeds `MAX_TO_RELEASE`. Generally, limits and parallel processing never play well.

Comment: Thanks for this thorough answer. I never use parallel streams. I'm still to experience their usefulness

Comment: I did not test, but the combiner seems to be wrong: `names.remove(MAX_TO_RELEASE);` should be replaced with `names.subList(MAX_TO_RELEASE, names.size()).clear();`.

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: mind that there’s a `.limit(MAX_TO_RELEASE+1)` before the collect operation. There can be at most one excess element. However, as already said, the effect of `resource.release()` has to be undone somehow in that case…

Comment: @Holger, ah I see. I checked the collector out of the overall context

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is

```
List<SomeResource> list = someResources();  // A List, rather than a Stream, is required
List<Integer> indices = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                                 .filter(i -> !list.get(i).isTaken())
                                 .limit(MAX_TO_RELEASE)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> names = indices.stream()
                            .map(list::get)
                            .peek(SomeResource::release)
                            .map(SomeResource::getName)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then (I think) there are unprocessed elements if

```
names.size() == MAX_TO_RELEASE 
    && (indices.isEmpty() || indices.get(indices.size() - 1) < list.size() - 1)
```

Comment: This is good, pity you need a list with all the resources to start with. Upvoted anyways

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Yes. If `someResources` returns a `Stream` you have to traverse the entire `Stream` to make a `List` even if the `limit` means that you shouldn't have to. For this reason, I think the `Iterator` version is superior. I don't think `Stream`s are suitable for this. You are trying to find out if `limit` has actually done anything, but this information is not exposed.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm trying to find out. Oh, it would be so good to know...